# get_filename_component gets a wrong file name

Tags: cmake

Is it a bug of CMake, or may I have a mistake? Can anybody point out that how to fix the problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

First, I listed a third party target's dll files. I do believe that it is ok.

```
project(assimp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set(ASSIMP_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

set(ASSIMP_NAME "assimp-vc142-mt")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES   "${ASSIMP_ROOT}/include"
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE         "${ASSIMP_ROOT}/lib/${ASSIMP_NAME}.lib"
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG           "${ASSIMP_ROOT}/lib/${ASSIMP_NAME}d.lib"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE       "${ASSIMP_ROOT}/bin/${ASSIMP_NAME}.dll"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG         "${ASSIMP_ROOT}/bin/${ASSIMP_NAME}d.dll")
```

Then, I wanted to use this lib, and the problem came.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

include(cmake/Functions.cmake)

project(my_show_case)

add_subdirectory(thirdparty)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

file(GLOB_RECURSE srcs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/*.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${srcs})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/)

get_property(ASSIMP_DEBUG_LIB TARGET assimp PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG)
get_property(ASSIMP_RELEASE_LIB TARGET assimp PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE)

# This section would get a wrong file name which has a '>' suffix
set(MY_Lib $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${ASSIMP_DEBUG_LIB}>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${ASSIMP_RELEASE_LIB}>)
get_filename_component(FILENAME "${MY_Lib}" NAME)
# prints: "assimp-vc142-mt.dll>"
file(GENERATE OUTPUT TestOut.txt CONTENT "${FILENAME}")
```

The file TestOut.txt would print "assimp-vc142-mt.dll>", as you can see, it has a suffix ">".

Comment: `get_filename_component` is resolved at configure time, not at build time. Generator expressions will not work.

Comment: @KamilCuk ooh, that's the matter! Thanks very much!! By the way, how can I tackle this situation?

Comment: "how can I tackle this situation?" - Just use **separate** calls to `get_filename_component`, one for `ASSIMP_DEBUG_LIB` and one for `ASSIMP_RELEASE_LIB`. Then combine results with generator expressions, as you do in `MY_Lib` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev got it and greatly appreciate.  Just seperate the build time function and run time function to make it work